# Fill array recursively in Julia using dot-notation and views

Tags: recursion, view, julia, vectorization

I am using Julia 1.9.0 and I’m trying to fill an array using views and dot notation where each entry depends on the preceding one(s). Say, I want the first 10 entries of the Fibonacci series in my array, so I initialize the first two entries and want the rest computed without a for-loop.

My approach was:

```
v = zeros(Int64, 10)
v[1:2] .= 1

@views v[3:10] .= v[1:8] .+ v[2:9]
v
```

Output:

```
10-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 2
 1
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
```

This doesn’t work, though, because apparently `v` doesn’t get updated before the next value is calculated. From reading the docs, I couldn’t find out why, because as far as I understood no arrays are copied and no temporary array is created. This should be equivalent to:

```
v = zeros(Int64, 10)
v[1:2] .= 1

@views a, b, c = v[1:8], v[2:9], v[3:10]
for i in 1:8
  c[i] = a[i] + b[i]
end
v
```

Output:

```
10-element Vector{Int64}:
  1
  1
  2
  3
  5
  8
 13
 21
 34
 55
```

Which is exactly the result I expected to get. Why doesn’t the first version work and is it possible to solve this without the for-loop?

Comment: I don't think there's any guarantee on the order of operations (for all we know, it could iterate backwards). Or if the operations are simd vectorized, for example, this won't work.

Comment: I would just use the for loop. It expresses the intent better (with no performance penalty) and recurrences like this can't be vectorized anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadcasting does alias detection. Therefore actually your operation copies data, because you have aliases.

To convince yourself that this is what happens check this code:

```
julia> v = zeros(Int64, 10^7);

julia> v[1:2] .= 1;

julia> @allocated v[3:end] .= @views v[1:end-2] .+ v[2:end-1]
```

This check is done using the `Base.mightalias` function.

Dealiasing is done to protect RHS to be affected by mutation of the LHS. So, on a basic level, the answer is that with broadcasting you cannot implement recursion.

However, you could create a custom type that would always return `false` in `Base.mightalias` aliasing check in which case what you ask for would work.

Here is an example:

```
julia> using SentinelArrays

julia> v = zeros(Int64, 10^7);

julia> v[1:2] .= 1;

julia> @allocated v[3:end] .= ChainedVector([@view v[1:end-2]]) .+ ChainedVector([@view v[2:end-1]])
800

julia> v
10000000-element Vector{Int64}:
                    1
                    1
                    2
                    3
                    5
                    8
                   13
                   21
                   34
                   55
                   89
                  144
                  233
                  377
                  610
                  987
                    ⋮
```

Comment: Thanks, this precisely answers the question. I didin’t know about dealiasing. It kind of feels like a hack, though, since the point of dealiasing is to actively prevent this mechanism from working, right? So going for the for-loop might be the more reasonable implementation...

Comment: Yes - if you want side effects, then you should use a loop. I just answered your question if it is possible to force broadcasting to allow for side effects, and since it is possible, I have shown you how :).